# Should my server support ipv6 to be able to get data when i use ipv6 internet

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, ipv6, ipv4

I am trying to add my application on app store but it returns this error 
that my application not support ipv6 and people told me that i should create ipv6 network to test my app.
now i have data on server but server which have this data doesn't support IPV6 only support IPV4 should it support IPV6 or it's ok to use IPV6 to get data from server that doesn't support IPV6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server can receive requests over IPv6 in two ways:
1) Your server support IPv6 and has IPv6 address (Also most hosting support this feature). 
2) Some device (hardware or Linux router) in front of the server should support both IPv6 and IPv4. It will receive requests over IPv6 and transmit them to your server over IPv4.

You may try to answer Appstore, that your hosting provider on server side do not support IPv6. For my case It worked.

Answer (score 1):

**This is a sensitive topic and many people have wrong knowledge about it.**

Your app MUST support IPv6-only networks. But your server MAY NOT support IPv6: it is up to you, to decide to support it or not.

**In-depth explanation**: Apple expects your client application to work correctly when connected to an IPv6-only network, **but that IPv6-only network MUST help your application by offering a DNS resolver that is DNS64 compliant (RFC 6147) and also offering a NAT64 (RFC 6146) IPv6-to-IPv4 translation gateway**. This means your client application makes a DNS request to *www.myipv4onlyserver.com* and the resolver replies with a fake IPv6 address routed to a NAT64 gateway. Thus, your client application talks with IPv6 to this gateway and this gateway translates the data channel to your IPv4 server, like a transparent proxy.

To be compliant with Apple expectations, use high-level network libraries and address-agnostic APIs, such as getaddrinfo() and getnameinfo(). Use hostnames or FQDN, not IP adresses.

See [this Apple forum article](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/46545) and [this Apple networking guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1) for further explanations.